# Print not working for MS Word docs with tables of contents (other factors seem N/A)

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

**ENVIRONMENT**

- Office Professional Plus 2019 / Single license (Click to run/C2R)
- Windows 10 / PC
- Updated Dec. 16, 2021 with build 14701.20262

**PROBLEM**

Documents of any size that have a table of contents (ToC) will no longer print a specified page or page range. There is no screen feedback of any kind; just a dead silent printer.

The ToC seems to be the only factor; in my tests in my environment, none of these factors have any bearing: the Office version, the Windows version, the presence or absence of sections, the sheer size of the document, the presence or absence of tables or figures, or starting in safe mode.

***Worked / Has Now Stopped Working***

```
Print > Settings > [Custom Print] > Pages: # > Print. 

Print > Settings > [Custom Print] > Pages: #-# > Print.
```

***Sometimes Works, Sometimes Doesn't***

```
Print > Settings > [Custom Print] > Pages: p#s#-p#s# > Print.
```

***Continues to Work as Expected***

```
 Print > Settings > [Print Current Page] > Print. 
    
 Print > Settings > [Print All Pages] > Print.
```

Comment: Please specify the Operating System and version of Word in your question. Please specify the "build." File > Account > About Word. There are multiple versions of Word in service and they have different characteristics. You may also want to try starting Word in safe mode and see if that makes a difference. https://support.office.com/article/dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72

Comment: Done. No effect. Added info to original post per your request.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

```
Go to: Options > Display > Printing Options
    
Check-in: Update Fields Before Printing
```

You will then have to respond to the "Update..." prompt every time you want to print the file. But at least the workaround works.

As long as the file is saved with this option in any Word file on the same drive, then the fix persists (because the set option becomes the same for all Word files).

These are the steps in Office/Word 2019 on Windows 10 on a PC, in a single-license environment. The steps may be different in other environments.

**OBSERVATION**

The problem started occurring after I had received a Word 365 file from someone. Whenever they send a file, the problem recurs. They work on an instution-provided Mac (I have a single-license PC).

**COMMENT**

This is a bug reported as far back as January 2021 that Microsoft keeps asserting is fixed with whatever the update-du-jour is. But as of today (Dec. 23, 2021) it is still not fixed. Also, at the Microsoft tech community site, the discussion seems to center on Word 365 used in multi-license, business environments.

The solution described above has consistently worked for me. I have tested it "six ways from Sunday" in my environment. Though it's a PITA to update multiple ToCs in large documents, changing the setting as described has worked without fail for me. So far.

For more information about the problem, see:

- [Printing a range of pages in a multi-section document stopped working](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/word/printing-a-range-of-pages-in-a-multi-section-document-stopped/m-p/2056379)
- [Word not printing selected pages when page numbering is set to Page 1 of X](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-not-printing-selected-pages-when-page/d4d80f01-2740-493f-a114-fb31ddf15e1f)

Scroll to the Doug Robbins reply on 9/22/21 with the graphics